# How to Draw a Rectangle 10cmx10cm on any Screen Device

Tags: javascript, css

Whatever the screen resolution recthangle renders 10cmx10cm on screen.

That means that if you take a ruler then you measure 10cmx10cm.

Can you do it with pure HTML and CSS or do you need javascript code also?

Comment: It can't be done as screen resolution doesn't tell you how large the actual pixels are. There's no way to know--via javascript--what the physical screen size is that is currently in use.

Comment: You can only get exact sizing when printing. Screen resolution causes visual adjustments because of pixel size. And, frankly, I can't think of a use case where I'd want this functionality.

Comment: @PredatorIWD sincerely interested if you could provide a link. AFAIK, this is impossible...you can't know what physical size of screen a user is using via JS.

Comment: You can use mm/cm in css but that's only going to help you when you print. You can't even be sure pixels are square.

Answer (score 1):

CSS actually supports centimeter units, just like pixels or percentages.
So you can just use :

```
#your-rectangle {
  width: 10cm;
  height: 10cm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<hr style="border:1px red solid;width: 10cm;height: 10cm;">
```

```html
<hr style="border:1px red solid;width: 10cm;height: 10cm;">
```

Comment: @RemiV2 'cause is almost your sollution i'll vote you

Comment: On a 28" (71cm) display set to 3840 x 2160 (UHD or "4k"), for me this draws a rectangle 6cm square. Set to 3200 x 1800, the square is 7.3cm. Set to 2650 x 1440 it's 9.1cm and at 1920 x 1080 (1080p or "fullHD") it's 12.2cm. Seems to me it does not do what the OP wants.